# Can I use a macro/function duplicate a weekly Excel sheet for every week using the correct dates?

Tags: excel

I have a schedule that has the dates M-F in various columns. I want to copy this week 1 into all 52 weeks of 2024 and have it automate with the correct dates by referencing the cell in the previous sheet. I can create the macro, but even if I reference sheet 1 with the second sheet, the third sheet will reference sheet 1 instead of sheet 2. Let me know if there is a macro tool that will allow me to do this without editing 52 sheets. Also, I don't know how to write VBA code, but feel free to send pre-written ones and I can load 'em up! Thanks.

I was trying to run a macro, but the automatization was not working as I had hoped. I wanted each consecutive sheet to reference the sheet before, so the Mondays would look something like =prevsheet(b4)+7 for 7 days a week, but it actually just referenced sheet 1. So instead of getting Jan 1, Jan 8, Jan 17 every time I used my keyboard shortcut, I just got Jan 1, Jan 8, Jan 8, etc etc. Thanks for any help you may have!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could work with something like this:

I have this on every sheet in cell A1:

```
MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1),1)+1,50)
```

Which gets the sheet name,

Then this gets a complete list of sheets between "Firstsheet" and "Lastsheet" :

```
TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", FALSE,Firstsheet:Lastsheet!A1),",")
```

and puts them into separate cells. Put all the relevant sheets between Firstsheet and Lastsheet.

Then you could use the incrementing column number to control the increase by 7 using the column() function.

I went this route to avoid using vba at all as the person needing this does not "do" vba...

Answer (score 0):

Assumed your sheets are in a sequential regular way (i.e. Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3...), and that your start date is in cell **B4** of the front sheet. Try it out see if it helps you to kick off.

```
Sub Add_Wks()
    Dim startSheet As Worksheet
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim startDateCell As Range
    Dim endDateCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set startSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set startDateCell = startSheet.Range("B4")
    Set endDateCell = startSheet.Range("B10")
    
    ' Loop
    For i = 1 To 51
        Set currentSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        currentSheet.Name = "Sheet" & i + 1
        startSheet.Cells.Copy currentSheet.Cells
        AdjustDates currentSheet.Range("B4:B10"), i * 7, startDateCell, endDateCell
    Next i
End Sub

Sub AdjustDates(rng As Range, offset As Integer, startCell As Range, endCell As Range)
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Formula = "=DATEADD(""d"", " & offset & ", " & cell.Offset(, -1).Address & ")"
    Next cell
    
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```